# Form don't accept null value symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony

when I make a post request with the value Null for my Files field. I have the following error :

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": {
        "period_from": "Cette valeur n'est pas valide.",
        "period_to": "Cette valeur n'est pas valide.",
        "files": "Cette valeur n'est pas valide.",
        "comment": "Cette valeur n'est pas valide.",
        "expenses": "Cette valeur n'est pas valide.",
        "employee": "Cette valeur n'est pas valide."
    }
}
```

however I do have a required false in my form and by consulting the profiler, it tells me the following sentence:

```
Compound forms expect an array or NULL on submission.
```

I need to be able to accept null because I'm passing my unit tests and I don't want to modify them.

I tried the 'required' => false, but no change

if I modify my query and remove the file field, the query works correctly :

```
{"employee":3,"period_from":"2018-01-01 00:00:00","period_to":null,"1":{"reference":"ref 3","type":1,"date":"2018-02-02 00:00:00","amount":500,"tax":15,"guest":"bidule","payment_method":0}},"files":null,"status":2}
```

My entity :

```
<?php

namespace WORD\ExpenseReportBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * ExpenseReport
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="w2d_exp_expenses_reports")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="W2D\ExpenseReportBundle\Repository\ExpenseReportRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deleteAt")
 */
class ExpenseReport
{
    /** Prefix for the file */
    const PREFIX_FILE = 'expense_report';

    /** Status */
    const STATUS_WAITING = 0;
    const STATUS_NEED_EDIT = 1;
    const STATUS_APPROVED = 2;
    const STATUS_REFUSED = 3;
    const STATUS_PAYED = 4;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report", "get_reports", "post_report", "put_report"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report", "get_reports"})
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d H:i:s'>")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleteAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d H:i:s'>")
     */
    private $deleteAt;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report", "get_reports"})
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="periodFrom", type="datetime")
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d H:i:s'>")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report", "get_reports"})
     */
    private $periodFrom;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * ©
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d H:i:s'>")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report", "get_reports"})
     */
    private $periodTo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="W2D\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="comment_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report"})
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="W2D\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="manager_comment_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report"})
     */
    private $managerComment;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="W2D\FileBundle\Entity\File")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="w2d_exp_reports_files",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="report_id",nullable=true, referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id") referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report"})
     * @Serializer\Type("array")
     */
    private $files;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="W2D\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report", "get_reports"})
     */
    private $employee;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="W2D\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="creator_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report", "get_reports"})
     */
    private $creator;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="W2D\ExpenseReportBundle\Entity\Expense", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="w2d_exp_reports_expenses",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="report_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="expense_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)})
     * @Serializer\Groups({"get_report", "get_reports"})
     */
    private $expenses;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->expenses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set comment
     *
     * @param mixed $comment
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get comment
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    /**
     * Set managerComment
     *
     * @param mixed $comment
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setManagerComment($comment)
    {
        $this->managerComment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get managerComment
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getManagerComment()
    {
        return $this->managerComment;
    }

    /**
     * Set employee
     *
     * @param \W2D\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee $employee
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setEmployee(\W2D\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee $employee)
    {
        $this->employee = $employee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get employee
     *
     * @return \W2D\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee
     */
    public function getEmployee()
    {
        return $this->employee;
    }

    /**
     * Set creator
     *
     * @param \W2D\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee $employee
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setCreator(\W2D\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee $employee)
    {
        $this->creator = $employee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get creator
     *
     * @return \W2D\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee
     */
    public function getCreator()
    {
        return $this->creator;
    }

    /**
     * Add expense
     *
     * @param \W2D\ExpenseReportBundle\Entity\Expense $expense
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function addExpense(\W2D\ExpenseReportBundle\Entity\Expense $expense)
    {
        $this->expenses[] = $expense;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove expense
     *
     * @param \W2D\ExpenseReportBundle\Entity\Expense $expense
     */
    public function removeExpense(\W2D\ExpenseReportBundle\Entity\Expense $expense)
    {
        $this->expenses->removeElement($expense);
    }


    /**
     * Get expenses
     *
     * @param $expenses
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setExpenses($expenses)
    {
        $this->expenses = $expenses;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get expenses
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getExpenses()
    {
        return $this->expenses;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param $date
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDeleteAt($date)
    {
        $this->deleteAt = $date;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeleteAt()
    {
        return $this->deleteAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set periodFrom
     *
     * @param \DateTime $periodFrom
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setPeriodFrom($periodFrom)
    {
        $this->periodFrom = $periodFrom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get periodFrom
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPeriodFrom()
    {
        return $this->periodFrom;
    }

    /**
     * Set periodTo
     *
     * @param \DateTime $periodTo
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function setPeriodTo($periodTo)
    {
        $this->periodTo = $periodTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get periodTo
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPeriodTo()
    {
        return $this->periodTo;
    }

    /**
     * Add file
     *
     * @param \W2D\FileBundle\Entity\File $file
     *
     * @return ExpenseReport
     */
    public function addFile(\W2D\FileBundle\Entity\File $file)
    {
        $this->files[] = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove file
     *
     * @param \W2D\FileBundle\Entity\File $file
     */
    public function removeFile(\W2D\FileBundle\Entity\File $file)
    {
        $this->files->removeElement($file);
    }

    /**
     * Get files
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFiles()
    {
        return $this->files;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your form entity is not supported null value. Please share your form entity here. It should be `nullable = true`

Comment: @BhavinNakrani thanks for your answer. I tried adding @ORM\Column(nullable=true). but I still have the same error. I added the entity in the post

Comment: @TubeCaribbean, did you run a migration to update your db? Also, remember to update you getter and setters to allow nullable value types.

Comment: hello @Bossman, No I don't run a migration, I run doctrine:schema:create and fixtures. How can I do that in my setters ?

Comment: @Bossman I was in the wrong class, I put the right class in the post above. I don't have the setter setFile, I only have addFile

Comment: the form doesn't care how the database looks, Bossman, it'll just look at getters and setters. Unless your php version is lower than 7.4, you should add the types to the parameters and add actual return types, instead of annotations. But I believe, symfony will respect annotations, and since `createdAt` is of type `\DateTime` it in fact can't be null. so turn that into `?\DateTime` and same for the others, and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your files field is rendering as array in twig. like this name="expenseReport[files]". There are three ways.

Please notice that instead of having it as `['files'=> $files]` it is actually `['files'=>['files'=>$files]]`. Lacking of this additional nesting level causes error mentioned into issue's subject.

1. Fix it with transformer (Recommended)

```
    namespace App\Form\Transformer;

    use App\DataObject\ExpenseReport;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
    
    class ExpenseReportModelTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
    {
        public function transform($value)
        {
            if ($value instanceof Upload) {
                return ['files' => ['files' => $value]];
            }
            return $value;
        }
    
        public function reverseTransform($value)
        {
            if (is_array($value) && ($value['files']['files'] ?? null) instanceof ExpenseReport) {
                return $value['files']['files'];
            }
            return $value;
        }
    }
```

View Transformer

```
namespace App\Form\Transformer;

use App\DataObject\ExpenseReport;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class ExpenseReportViewTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value) && ($value['files']['files'] ?? null) instanceof ExpenseReport) {
            return $value['files']['files'];
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if ($value instanceof ExpenseReport) {
            return ['files' => ['files' => $value]];
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Form should look like this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('files', VichFileType::class, [
                'required'          => true,
                'allow_file_upload' => true,
            ])
            ->addModelTransformer(new ExpenseReportModelTransformer())
            ->addViewTransformer(new ExpenseReportViewTransformer())
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, static function (FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                if (is_array($data) && ($data['files'] ?? null) instanceof UploadedFile) {
                    $data['files'] = ['files' => $data['files']];
                    $event->setData($data);
                }
            });
    }

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ExpenseReport::class,
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return '';
    }
```

2. Set Empty data

```
$resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'empty_data'   => "",
                'data_class' => ExpenseReport::class
            ]
        );
```

3. Compound value set a false

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'compound'   => false,
                'data_class' => ExpenseReport::class
            ]
        );
    }
```